# How to calculate the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(t)dt$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

For a function $g(t)$, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt=\omega e^{-2\omega ^2}$ for any real value $\omega$. If $y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(\tau)d\tau$ then how to calculate the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(t)dt$?

Comment: What is $j$? Integer? Real? Imaginary unit?

Comment: Probably $j^2 =-1$, standard electrical engineer notation.

Comment: @Fantini or $j^2=-1,$ with $j \in \mathbb{H}$...

Answer (score 1):

To compute $\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} y(t) \, dt$ you can find its Fourier transform $Y(\omega)$ and evaluate that zero: $$Y(0) = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} y(t) \, dt.$$ By Fourier transform properties we know $$Y(w) = \mathcal{F} \{ y(t) \} = \mathcal{F} \left\{ \int_{- \infty}^t g(\tau) \, d \tau \right\} = \frac{\mathcal{F}\{g(t)\}}{j \omega}.$$ What you are given is precisely the Fourier transform of $g(t)$, therefore $$Y(\omega) = \frac{\omega e^{-2 \omega^2}}{j \omega} = \frac{e^{-2 \omega^2}}{j}.$$ Finally $$Y(0) = \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} y(t) \, dt = \frac{1}{j}.$$